# Adding SQL Parameter fails

Tags: vb.net, parameters

This is a new concept for me and I can't quite see what's causing the error
I'm attempting to populate a datagridview control from a single field in an Access database (from a combo and Text box source).
Using literals works, but not with the parameter.

```
Dim conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Backend & ";Persist Security Info=False;")
    Dim command As New OleDbCommand("Select Year from tblTest ", conn)
    Dim criteria As New List(Of String)

    If Not cboYear.Text = String.Empty Then
        criteria.Add("Year = @Year")
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Year", cboYear.Text)
    End If

    If criteria.Count > 0 Then
        command.CommandText &= " WHERE " & String.Join(" AND ", criteria)
    End If

    Dim UserQuery As New OleDbDataAdapter(command.CommandText, conn)
    Dim UserRet As New DataTable
    UserQuery.Fill(UserRet)

    With frmDGV.DataGridView2
        .DataSource = UserRet
    End With

    frmDGV.DataGridView2.Visible = True
    frmDGV.Show()
```

Trying to Fill the datatable shows exception 'No value given for one or more required parameters.'

The value of command.CommandText at that point is "Select Year from tblTest WHERE Year = @Year"

Comment: Looks like VB.  Add the language-appropriate tag to your question.

Comment: Tried but it wouldn't allow me

Answer (score 2):

Your instance of `OleDbDataAdapter` was created using two parameters query text and connection.

```
Dim UserQuery As New OleDbDataAdapter(command.CommandText, conn)
```

In this case DataAdapter doesn't know about parameters at all.

Instead use constructor with paremeter of  type `OleDbCommand`.

```
Dim UserQuery As New OleDbDataAdapter(command)
```

In your code instance of `OleDbCommand` already associated with connection